# Python: Create a model for reports (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This is more of a model design question with python.

I need to parse and extract data from several log files into a pandas DataFrames.
From these dataframes I need to create reports (as csv, excel and so on).

One way of design such is to create a file with 2 functions:
1. function to extract data from log file (regex is fine)
2. function of pandas query, something like this:

```
def get_top1000(group):

  return group.sort_index(by='births', ascending=False)[:1000]
  grouped = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])
  top1000 = grouped.apply(get_top1000)
```

Then, my class could get all these queries and produce the reports for this.
How this can be implemented with python correctly?

Comment: *How this can be implemented with python correctly?*...what is being done incorrectly? *my class could get all this queries and produce the reports for this.*...you want us to build your class? This is too broad a question. You tell us nothing about your *model* or what needs to be extracted and reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])['births'].nlargest(1000)
```

Sample:

```
names = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000],
                   'sex':['M','M','F','F','F'],
                   'births':[7,8,9,1,2]})

print (names)
   births sex  year
0       7   M  2000
1       8   M  2000
2       9   F  2000
3       1   F  2000
4       2   F  2000

df = names.groupby(['year', 'sex'])['births']
          .nlargest(1)
          .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
          .reset_index()
print (df)
   year sex  births
0  2000   F       9
1  2000   M       8
```

If in your data there are other columns, first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with these columns:

```
names = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000],
                   'sex':['M','M','F','F','F'],
                   'births':[7,8,9,1,2],
                    'val':[3,2,4,5,6]})

print (names)
   births sex  val  year
0       7   M    3  2000
1       8   M    2  2000
2       9   F    4  2000
3       1   F    5  2000
4       2   F    6  2000

df = names.set_index('val') \
          .groupby(['year', 'sex'])['births'] \
          .nlargest(1) \
          .reset_index()
print (df)
   year sex  val  births
0  2000   F    4       9
1  2000   M    2       8
```